# Adding data to ManyToManyField after creation

Tags: python, django

I've got a model with a ManyToManyField and want to add all data out of a different table upon creation of that model. 
This is the code I got so far, which does not save the entries:

```
'''
Klassendefinition für den Spieltag
'''

from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from django_extensions.db.models import TimeStampedModel

from season.models import Season
from player.models import Player

# Create your models here.

class Matchday(TimeStampedModel):
    '''
    Klasse für den Spieltag
    '''

    seasontable = models.ManyToManyField("table.Table", related_name="Ligaspieltisch", blank=True)
    matchtable = models.ManyToManyField("table.Table", related_name="Pfeilsystemtisch", blank=True)
    #Spieler die am Spieltag angemeldet sind (Kickereuro)
    signedin = models.ManyToManyField("player.Player", related_name="Angemeldet", blank=True)

    needtopay = models.BooleanField(_("Soll der Kickereuro gezahlt werden?"), default=True)
    finished = models.BooleanField(_("Beendet?"), default=False)

    season = models.ForeignKey(Season, verbose_name=_("Saison"), blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        '''
        Metaklasse für Spieltag
        '''
        verbose_name = _("Spieltag")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Spieltage")
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Spieltag"

@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=Matchday)
def execute_after_save(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    '''
    Ausführen, wenn matchday gespeichert wird
    '''
    if created: #Wurde matchday neu erstellt?
        if not instance.needtopay:
            #Kickereuro muss nicht gezahlt werden -> alle Spieler hinzufügen
            instance.save()
            players = Player.objects.all()
            players = list(players)
            for player in players:
                instance.signedin.add(player)
            instance.save()
            players = instance.signedin.all()
            print(players)
```

The **print(players)** is there for debugging purposes and returns the list of players correctly, but they are not saved.
I tried it without **instance.save()** at start and **instance.signedin.add(*players)**, which both did not work. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you determining that they are "not saved"?

Comment: Simply by looking into the admin interface or my REST API...
This is the API after creation:
`[
    {
        "id": 19,
        "seasontable": [
            2
        ],
        "matchtable": [
            1
        ],
        "signedin": [],
        "needtopay": false,
        "finished": false,
        "season": 1
    }
]`

Comment: **instance.signedin.add(*players)** should work, does  **print players** print something?

Comment: This is how it should look like:
`[
    {
        "id": 19,
        "seasontable": [
            2
        ],
        "matchtable": [
            1
        ],
        "signedin": [
            1,
            4
        ],
        "needtopay": false,
        "finished": false,
        "season": 1
    }
]`

Comment: **print(players)** outputs the list of all players, as it should do. As I said, I tried it with **instance.signedin.add(*players)**, which also did not work

Comment: The Output of **print(players)**: `<QuerySet [<Player: Artus>, <Player: Kerstin>]>`